# when i try to install android studio in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, unsupported-class-version

[image]

how can I solve this. please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 0):

You current java version is probably outdated.

Run on the command-line: `java -version` to check your current JRE version.

Then install Java 1.8 or above.